# How to make user input not case sensitive in Python?

Tags: python

I made an boat adventure text based game and i found a problem that is very easy to accidentally type wrong.How to i solve this problem? Here is my code

```
sleep = input("Its 11:45 what you do go to bed or stay awake till 4 am?")
scenarios = ['A fish jumped on the boat and woke you up', 'You wake up needing to go to the toilet and accidentally trip and fall into the ocean']
if sleep == "sleep":
    event = random.choice(scenarios)
    print(event)
if event == "A fish jumped on the boat and woke you up"
    action = input("What you do? throw it back into the ocean or catch him?")
    if action == "throw it back into the ocean":
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the string to lower or upper case before doing the comparison.

```
if action.lower() == "throw it back into the ocean"
```

Comment: oh it gave me a syntax error but i solved it was because of me thanks for the help!